# Boxes not colliding with each other

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I want two boxes two collide with each other but they don't. I have triangulated the faces and the rigidbody has dynamic and active on. Keyframes have been set with the end keyframes ending up with the boxes at the same location.

Comment: Is this for the game engine? Do you have a blend file you can post?

Comment: @AnthonyForwood It is tagged [tag:rigid-body-simulation].

Comment: @Shady Puck - I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood It's like the game engine, but a lot simpler. It's what Scratch is to Python (coding languages) or Cycles (Blender) to Renderman (Pixar). See BlenderGuru's awesome beginner tutorial called [Quick Rigid Body Fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY).

Comment: What????? I mean I don't know what tagging means or what telling me that has to do with anything.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood All questions have tags at the bottom indicating their subject areas. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works

Comment: @TonyCorin can you upload your file? Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and **[edit]** the resulting link as part of the text in your question

Comment: I thought I did. So much excess stuff on websites in general that I can't be bothered to read every little thing or spend a lot of time searching for what is claimed to be there. Not my fault. Important things need to be more distinct./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, it seems you are trying to use *dynamic* rigid bodies with keyframes, but haven't set them up to allow the animation system to take over the simulation. There is a difference between the two setups, so I will leave a basic example of of how this can be done:

**First the difference between the two:**

Dynamic rigid bodies-

strictly controlled by physics:

[image]

Animated rigid bodies-

controlled by the animation system until you change this!:

[image]

**Here's how to set it up:**

**1.** Add a rigid body simulation. Active, and dynamic, **and** select
    *animated*. Also, use the *collision margin*, and set this fairly high. The limit is 1. Do this for both objects. You can also play with the *mass* options if you like. Also, apply transforms with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*>rotation & scale*

[image]

**2.** Insert a *location* keyframe at frame 1 for each object with <kbd>I</kbd>*>location*.

**3.** Select and add a keyframe to the animated checkbox in the physics panel at the same
    frame the simulation will begin by hovering over the checkbox and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

**4.** Set your end keyframe for the collision of your objects, and again choose *location*, or what whatever is applicable to your needs.

**5.** At the *frame following the collsion* **uncheck** the animated
    option in the rigid body options for each object, and set a new
    keyframe.

From this you should be able to expand and make many interesting simulations from colliding cubes to anything else.